# Windows UWP crashing when uploaded to Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm having a major problem with my app [Small Acorns Vegetarian Recipes](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh2rqt4) when uploaded to the Windows Store.

When I test the app locally, then create App Package and test by sideloading the app I cannot replicate the errors that are occurring from the live app in the store. I have also downloaded the live app on 3 different Windows 10 devices and the app works without crashing.

Below is the crash report from Windows Dev center which is recording this error as a `STOWED_EXCEPTION` of type `System.UnAuthorizedException`. There are multiple errors but they all look the same as the one below.

> 9NBLGGH2RQT4  Small Acorns    2016-W3 1/18/2016 12:00:00 AM   e5fbe8d3-2fcc-9405-e339-795d8ec35826    "1 SmallAcorns_W10_7ffbdf7a0000  0xC179E8
>   2 SmallAcorns_W10_7ffbdf7a0000  0xFCD461
>   3 SmallAcorns_W10_7ffbdf7a0000  0xFF7263"
>   9NBLGGH2RQT4    Small Acorns    2016-W3 1/18/2016 12:00:00 AM   45df7950-ae20-259c-3f6e-4ec2a1758559    "1 SmallAcorns_W10_581b0000  0x98DC05
>   2 SmallAcorns_W10_581b0000  0x98DE13
>   3 SmallAcorns_W10_581b0000  0xC14E95
>   4 SmallAcorns_W10_581b0000  0xC14E5E
>   5 SmallAcorns_W10_581b0000  0xC14E49
>   6 SmallAcorns_W10_581b0000  0xC14BC3
>   7 SharedLibrary System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw 0x1C
>   8 SharedLibrary $13_System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess 0x4A
>   9 SharedLibrary $13_System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification 0x3C
>   10 SharedLibrary $13_System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd 0x16
>   11 SharedLibrary $13_System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ConfiguredTaskAwaitable::ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult 0x9
>   12 SmallAcorns_W10_581b0000  0xC1548C
>   13 SharedLibrary System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw 0x1C
>   14 SharedLibrary $22_System::Threading::Tasks::ExceptionDispatchHelper::__c__DisplayClass0._ThrowAsync_b__3 0x19
>   15 SharedLibrary $13_System::Threading::WinRTSynchronizationContext::Invoker.InvokeCore 0x3C"

The health reports are next to useless as its clearly an async method failing and I cannot now download the `.cab` files to test with `WinDbg` (like you could with Windows 8.1 apps)
I have absolutely no idea where this error is occurring in the app as the app works on the multiple devices I've tested it on.
Has anyone managed to use WinDbg with an universal app? Any help much appreciated as I am totally stuck with this issue.

If anyone has the time to test my app as its hidden but available from the link above that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

is the problem happen only on your device? 
for the debugging tool, you can use the updated one for Windows 10 :)

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

[Debugging tools for Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/mt219728(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: no as I said in the question its happening on user devices when they have downloaded the app from the store.

Comment: I've downloaded the app, it's working perfectly.. have you tried the attached links for WinDbg?

Comment: Thx for trying the app. Yes I've attached WinDbg using plmdebug.exe to the live store app and no major exceptions. Perhaps I just need to catch Application.UnHandledException and I'll be ok but I've had 106 crashes with not many downloads (under 100).

Comment: Yes, try to handle the general unhandled exception event and try to run the app in Visual Studio under release mode.. you could face the same exceptions :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because "chain compilation" and/or "code optimization" when in Release. Try to set them off one by one or all at the same time and and start debugging in Release on a device. You want be able to see all the info like when build in Debug, but at least you'll be able to find where and why your app crashes.

Comment: thx for the tip will test again more thoroughly in Release mode this week and report back